# Reverse circular motion

Tags: objective-c, math

I have a query relating to reverse circular motion. I have the code below. case 1 is clockwise circular motion and case 2 is anticlockwise. The switch between case 1 and 2 is done with a user touch. When it switches from clockwise to anticlockwise it uses the same value in the `sin()` and `cos()` which is `timer/1.5`. This causes the anticlockwise motion to begin from a different position on my planet. I want to calculate the value that is required for my timer in order for the anticlockwise motion to start from where it left off during the clockwise motion and thus have a smooth transition. Does anyone know the correct Math for this as my mind is stuck?

Just a small explanation of the code below. I am calculating the position of my Robot by taking the x and y coordinates of the Planet it is on and performing a circular motion with a radius of the Planet's radius + 55 (which is a comfortable height for my sprite).

```
        case 1:

        positionX = AttachedPlanet.positionX + sin(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
        positionY = AttachedPlanet.positionY + cos(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
        timer = timer + 0.02;

        break;
    case 2:



        positionX = AttachedPlanet.positionX + cos(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
        positionY = AttachedPlanet.positionY + sin(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
        timer = timer + 0.02;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just keep the same function and switch to decrementing the timer? If you need some measure of total time, maintain a second timer that always goes up.

Comment: Oh boy - how did I miss that? Thanks for the reply! I think my head was stuck in a loop :D . I've decided to use the same function and add an additional timer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

To switch direction, you need to subtract the sin/cos results.  So something like

```
dir = +1; //initialization

if (switchDirection) //event handling
    dir *= -1;

//calculation
positionX = AttachedPlanet.positionX + dir*cos(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
positionY = AttachedPlanet.positionY + dir*sin(timer/1.5)*(AttachedPlanet.planetRadius + 55);
```